# replace letters in python string

Tags: python

Im writing a program for french that turns present tense verbs into past tense. The problem is that I need to replace letters but they are user inputed so I have to have it replacing the letters from the end of the line. Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't change the letters it just gives an error:

```
word = raw_input("what words do you want to turn into past tense?")
word2= word

if word2.endswith("re"):
 word3 = word2.replace('u', 're')
 print word3

elif word2.endswith("ir"):
 word2[-2:] = "i"
 print word2

elif word2.endswith("er"):
 word2[-2:] = "e"
 print word2

else:
 print "nope"
```

I tried word replace and that doesn't work either, it just gives me back the same string. If some one could just give me an example and maybe explain it a little that would be awesome. :/

Comment: split the 'word' string to a list contain individual words and loop through it while check it with endswith

Comment: It would be good if you show your input, output and expected output.

Comment: i really have no idea how to do that im pretty new :/

Comment: I have no idea about French, but usually grammar is very complex and not always regular (especially not based on two characters within words), so I doubt you’ll be able to get any well working solution using simple search&replaces…

Comment: actualy thats a very valid point, thing is for past participle there is a very definete way of doing it, its exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is inmutable, so u can't replace only the 2 last letters... you must create a new string from the existant.

and as said by MM-BB, replace will replace all the ocurance of the letter...

try

```
word = raw_input("what words do you want to turn into past tense?")
word2 = word

if word2.endswith("re"):
    word3 = word2[:-2] + 'u'
    print word3

elif word2.endswith("ir"):
    word3 = word2[:-2] + "i"
    print word3

elif word2.endswith("er"):
    word3 = word2[:-2] + "e"
    print word3

else:
    print "nope"
```

ex 1 :

```
what words do you want to turn into past tense?sentir
senti
```

ex 2 :

```
what words do you want to turn into past tense?manger
mange
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO there might be a problem with the way you are using replace. The syntax for replace is explained. [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

```
string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
```

This ipython session might be able to help you.

```
In [1]: mystring = "whatever"

In [2]: mystring.replace('er', 'u')
Out[2]: 'whatevu'

In [3]: mystring
Out[3]: 'whatever'
```

basically the pattern you want replaced comes first, followed by the string you want to replace with.

Answer (score 0):

excuse me

```
word3 = word2.replace('u', 're')
```

above line code can make a false result because
maybe exist another "er" in your word

Answer (score 0):

I think that regular expressions will be a better solution here, and the [subn](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn) method in particular.

```
import re

word = 'sentir'

for before, after in [(r're$','u'),(r'ir$','i'),(r'er$','e')]:
    changed_word, substitutions  = re.subn(before, after, word)
    if substitutions:
        print changed_word
        break
else:
    print "nope"
```

Answer (score 0):

essentially what you've done wrong is "word2.replace('u', 're')" This means that you are replace 'u' with 're' inside the var word2. I have changed the code;

```
 word = raw_input("what words do you want to turn into past tense?")
 word2= word

 if word2.endswith("re"):
    word3 = word2.replace('re', 'u')
    print word3

  elif word2.endswith("ir"):
     word2[-2:] = "i"
     print word2

 elif word2.endswith("er"):
    word2[-2:] = "e"
    print word2

 else:
     print "nope"
```