# python, help replacing first letters

Tags: python, replace

I need to replace the first letters of a string. What command should I use?
I'm writing a thing for French that changes words into past tense and I have done the bit for the last letters i.e. `re` turns into u but I need to do the one that changes `je` into `j'ai`

```
word = raw_input("what words do you want to turn into past tense?")
word2= word

if word2.endswith("re"):
    word3 = word2[:-2] + "u"
    print word3
elif word2.endswith("ir"):
    word3 = word2[:-2] + "i"
    print word3
elif word2.endswith("er"):
    word3 = word2[:-2] + "e"
    print word3
else:
    print "nope"
```

this is what i have done so far

Comment: sorry i dont know where the spacing went but it is supossed to be on the collons and the print

Comment: you could use the same method, just change the slice notation from `[:-2]` to `[2:]`

Comment: Are you planning to extend this to cope with a) the verbs that take *être* as their auxiliary verb and b) the irregular verbs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace letters in python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528228/replace-letters-in-python-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like this

```
word = 'tu as'
changes = {'je': "j'ai", 'tu':'tu as'}
changes.get(word, 'Nope')
```

it will give you the change you need from "I/you" to "I/you did".

This is a very naive stab at making a translator... You may as well just put all of the terms in the same dictionary i.e.

```
changes = {'re':'u', 'ir':'i', 'er':'e', 'je': "j'ai", 'tu':'tu as'}
```

and then iterate through each word in the "from" sentence to the convert it to the equivalent past tense word.

Disclaimer: Of course this doesn't consider the grammar of the language you are using. Full translation is substantially more involved than this "a-for-b" type of exchange.

Comment: the question is about changing the first letters of the string

Comment: @user2191568 Updated. Is this what you want?